# How do you re-transmit a .m3u8 live stream with changed bitrate, fps etc. with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, transcoding

For instance, I have a 720p/60/4mbps stream, I want to re-stream/re-tranmist it as a 360p/60/1mps stream. Is it possible with ffmpeg?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. All you need to use something like `ffmpeg -i "udp://sourceip:[port]" -vcodec libx264 -vb 150000 -muxrate 1M -r 60 -g 60 -vprofile baseline -level 2.1 -acodec aac -ab 64000 -ar 48000 -ac 2 -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -strict experimental -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:10000`

Not tested.

Comment: Thanks, the incoming stream is actually a twitch stream (ending in a .m3u8), could I rencode that Would that be possible?

Comment: try this, replace `-i udp://sourceip:[port]` to `-i twitch.m3u8`.